# How do I compare just the digits in two excel columns?

Tags: excel, compare

For example:

Column A: (215) 640-1037
Column B: 215.640.1037

I just want to compare just the digits in the two columns to see if they are the same, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

UDF Time! Put this function into your workbook, then enter in column C `=compare(a1,b1)`

```
Public Function COMPARE(Value1 As String, Value2 As String) As Boolean
Dim subVal1 As String
Dim subVal2 As String

subVal1 = ""
subVal2 = ""

For x = 1 To Len(Value1)
    If IsNumeric(Left(Value1, 1)) Then
        subVal1 = subVal1 & Left(Value1, 1)
    End If
    Value1 = Right(Value1, Len(Value1) - 1)
Next x

For x = 1 To Len(Value2)
    If IsNumeric(Left(Value2, 1)) Then
        subVal2 = subVal2 & Left(Value2, 1)
    End If
    Value2 = Right(Value2, Len(Value2) - 1)
Next x

If subVal1 = subVal2 Then
    COMPARE = True
Else
    COMPARE = False
End If

End Function
```

Comment: For anyone trying this code, I had to add a Module to the **VBAProject** for the workbook (file.xlsm) and put the code there for it to show up when I typed `=COMPARE`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",""),")","")," ",""),"-",""),".","")=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"(",""),")","")," ",""),"-",""),".","")
```

Comment: I just want to know if the digits are the same and if they are, have the new column read "True" and if not, have it read, "False"

Comment: This seemed to work.  You have to change the `A1` and `B1` references to point to your cells.